# when client is closed server crash

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp, server, client

I have a problem when I connect to the server from the client, it connects without any issues, but when I close the client window, the server shows the following error message:

```
The length can not be less than zero. Parameter name: length
```

And then when I try to reconnect the client it crashes too

This is the server source code:

```
    serverSocket.Start()
    AddInfo("Server Started", ConsoleColor.Cyan)

    AddInfo("---------------- ACCOUNTS ----------------", ConsoleColor.Blue)
    Dim AN As Integer = 0
    For Each f In Directory.GetFiles("saved\accounts\")
        Dim acc As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).Split(CChar("%"))(0)
        Dim pass As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).Split(CChar("%"))(1)
        AddInfo(acc & " - " & pass, ConsoleColor.Magenta)
        AN += 1
    Next
    AddInfo(AN & " Accounts exists .", ConsoleColor.DarkCyan)
    AddInfo("-----------------------------------------------", ConsoleColor.Blue)

    clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient()
    AddInfo("New Client Connected", ConsoleColor.Yellow)
    clients_number += 1
    AddInfo("Clients Num : " & clients_number, ConsoleColor.DarkYellow)
    requestCount = 0

    While (True)
        'RECEIVING
        requestCount = requestCount + 1
        serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
        Dim bytesFrom(10024) As Byte
        serverStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, CInt(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
        Dim dataFromClient As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom)
        dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"))
        AddInfo("Data from client -  " + dataFromClient, ConsoleColor.DarkYellow)

        '### CHEKING ACCOUNT ###
        For Each f In Directory.GetFiles("saved\accounts\")
            If dataFromClient = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f) Then
                account_avaible = True
            End If
        Next
        If account_avaible = True Then
            Dim serverResponse As String = ""
            Dim l As New List(Of String)
            l.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("saved\accounts\" & dataFromClient & ".inf"))
            For i = 0 To l.Count - 1
                serverResponse += l.Item(i).ToString.Split(CChar("="))(1) & "|"
            Next
            Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse)
            serverStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
            serverStream.Flush()
            AddInfo(serverResponse, ConsoleColor.Green)
        Else
            Dim serverResponse As String = "connection_false"
            Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse)
            serverStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
            serverStream.Flush()
            AddInfo(serverResponse, ConsoleColor.Green)
            account_avaible = False
        End If
    End While
```

Comment: No error handling. Not one. I never did any vb.net development, but if I'd have to guess, I'd say your problems start here: `serverStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, CInt(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))`. Probably, `clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize` is negative to indicate that some error occurred. You need to do error handling and ensure that `serverStream.Read()` is not called with a negative length (which apparently is what's happening). Someone with vb.net experience might shed some light into this, but I'd start from there.

Comment: I'm going to guess that at some point when it closes, the clients sends a string without "$", then this line `dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"))` crashes because `dataFromClient.IndexOf("$")` returns -1 as there's no "$"

Comment: if i remove the $ the server will bug

Comment: When you close the client, the while(true) loop causes the server to try to read from a no-longer-existent stream.  The line clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient() blocks until a connection is made, which is why it will not crash before the client connects, but it is already inside the loop when the client disconnects.  Check for a valid connection prior to each read from the stream.

Comment: As for the client crashing too when you try to reconnect, of course it does.  There is no longer a server listening for it to connect to.  Put your server stream read in a try catch block and your client code as well, in line with @FilipeGonçalves's comments above.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this problem . thanks @WDS .
 i deleted the loop and i made a return to the `clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient()`

this is the source :

`serverSocket.Start() : AddInfo("Server Started", ConsoleColor.Cyan)

```
    AddInfo("---------------- ACCOUNTS ----------------", ConsoleColor.Blue)
    Dim AN As Integer = 0
    For Each f In Directory.GetFiles("saved\accounts\")
        Dim acc As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).Split(CChar("%"))(0)
        Dim pass As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).Split(CChar("%"))(1)
        AddInfo(acc & " - " & pass, ConsoleColor.Magenta)
        AN += 1
    Next
    AddInfo(AN & " Accounts exists .", ConsoleColor.DarkCyan)
    AddInfo("-----------------------------------------------", ConsoleColor.Blue)
```

Dodo:

```
    account_avaible = False
    clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient()
    AddInfo("New Client Connected", ConsoleColor.Yellow)
    clients_number += 1
    AddInfo("Clients Num : " & clients_number, ConsoleColor.DarkYellow)
    requestCount = 0

        'RECEIVING
        requestCount = requestCount + 1
        serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
        Dim bytesFrom(10024) As Byte
        serverStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize)
        Dim dataFromClient As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom)
        dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"))
        AddInfo("Data from client -  " + dataFromClient, ConsoleColor.DarkYellow)

        '### CHEKING ACCOUNT ###
        For Each f In Directory.GetFiles("saved\accounts\")
            If dataFromClient = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f) Then
                account_avaible = True
            End If
        Next
        If account_avaible = True Then
            Dim serverResponse As String = ""
            Dim l As New List(Of String)
            l.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("saved\accounts\" & dataFromClient & ".inf"))
            For i = 0 To l.Count - 1
                serverResponse += l.Item(i).ToString.Split(CChar("="))(1) & "|"
            Next
            Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse)
            serverStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
            serverStream.Flush()
            AddInfo(serverResponse, ConsoleColor.Green)
        Else
            Dim serverResponse As String = "connection_false"
            Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse)
            serverStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
            serverStream.Flush()
            AddInfo(serverResponse, ConsoleColor.Green)
            account_avaible = False
    End If

    GoTo Dodo

    'clientSocket.Close()
    'serverSocket.Stop()`
```

But now i have new problem =/ when i enter an incorrect account msg show ("Incorrect account") and then when i try to enter an other account the client bugg (freeze)